# Wrapping using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a variable `wrapper` with data:

```
<div class="elementwrapper" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >    
<span class="edittool">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil editpencil" onclick="editContent(this);" style="padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok editok" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove editcancel" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
</span>     
</div>
```

I want to wrap my current elements data inside the `span` with class `edittool`. I used:

```
$(currentElement).wrap(wrapper);
```

But what I am getting is:

```
 <div class="elementwrapper" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >   
<span class="edittool">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil editpencil" onclick="editContent(this);" style="padding:0 5px 0 0;">
        MY DATA
    </span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok editok" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove editcancel" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
</span>     
</div>
```

It should be inside `edittool` `span` and after all its inner `spans`. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this. What is currentElement and wrapper in this context?

Comment: But what you want? You say "I want to wrap my current elements data inside the span with class edittool.", but it seems you have a problem with the variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.append()` to put your data inside span. see below code

```js
$(function(){
   var wrapper = "MY DATA";
   $('span.edittool').append(wrapper);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elementwrapper" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >   
<span class="edittool">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil editpencil" onclick="editContent(this);" style="padding:0 5px 0 0;">
    </span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok editok" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove editcancel" onclick="doneEdit(this);" style="display:none;padding:0 5px 0 0;"></span>
</span>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var content = "<div class='new'></div>";
$( ".edittool" ).wrapInner( content );
```